# Swapping X,Y coordinates in a rectangle, what is this operation called?

Tags: math, coordinates

Trying to find a good name for a method swapping each coordinate X and Y values.

Is there a name for this operation?

Essentially, here's what is done

> (1, 2) -> (2, 1)

On a polygon, this is the same as having a rotation of -90 degrees and doing a horizontal flip or mirror.

Comment: Please be careful people, Eric Bainville and Andriyev answer's are not quite correct.

Comment: Please be careful Alex, because you are wrong. :-)

BTW, the "Transpose" answer does not make sense. We are looking for the name of an affine transformation here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a matrix, it is called the [**Transpose**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

Comment: I like that. Does it fit well for a polygon?

Comment: Transpose is not -90 degree rotation followed by a horizontal flip. It is a horizontal flip, followed by a -90 degree rotation. The result is totally different.

Comment: @CarlosOst is correct.   I have no memory of writing this answer over 10 years ago, but it is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 11):

This is called a reflection, or line symmetry.  In your case, the line is X=Y.  It is invariant by the symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

It would be reflection about line x=y which is one of the transformations in coordinate geometry.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want a [transpose](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Transpose.html) it would turn the row vector (1 2) into a column vector (1 2), so your question and example with the (1, 2) is a little unclear. Abstractly:

```
array=[[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [ 11.,   0.,   3.],
       [ 22.,  33.,   0.]]
transposed_array=transpose(array).
print transposed_array 
       [[  0.,  11.,  22.],
       [  1.,   0.,  33.],
       [  2.,   3.,   0.]]
```

It is NOT a reflection about x=y (at best x=-y and only for square matrices).  Please look at the link abelenky posted on [transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose). Eric Bainville and Andriyev answer's would be closer to correct if they said x=-y, but never technically sufficient.  Also, it is NOT a [matrix inversion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html) which involves changing the values of individual components.  If I interpret your statement "rotation of -90 degrees [that is 90 degrees clockwise] and doing a horizontal flip or mirror." correctly, then this is indeed the correct answer.